# How to only select items from a list with certain property set to true

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Collection called `ItemCollection` that looks like:

```
public class ItemCollection : List<Item>
{
}
```

The `Item` has a property called `MyProperty`:

```
public class Item
{
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a `ItemManager` that has a `GetItems` method which returns an `ItemCollection`.

Now I want to only get items from my `ItemCollection`  with `MyProperty`  set to true.

I tried:

```
ItemCollection ic = ItemManager.GetItems().Where(i => i.MyProperty);
```

Unfortunately the `Where` part does not work. Although `i` refers to an `Item` I get the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type Item to ItemCollection.

How can I filter the returned `ItemCollection` to only contain those `Item`s that have `MyProperty` set to true?

Comment: The where part is probably ok, but the returned value is an IEnumerable<Item> and cannot be assigned to `ic` which is of type `ItemCollection`

Comment: Is this the exact code? I don't see anything trying to convert an `Item` to an `ItemCollection`.

Comment: The error seems to indicate you're using `First`, `Single` etc. instead of `Where`.

Comment: @KendallFrey No, in reality the code is more complex (too much to post here), but I do not see what the issue can be.

Comment: In that case you should reproduce the problem with some simpler code. It's very hard to diagnose a problem when the code and error message don't match.

Comment: Could you try to change `ItemCollection ic = ItemManager.GetItems.....` to `var ic = ItemManager.GetItems.....` and then tell us what the type of `ic` is, please? I feel like we may be missing something simple, due to the IDE being confused and giving a different error message than would be expected.

Comment: Type is `Systems.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

Comment: Exactly what I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension functions are **Great** solution too :

```
public static class Dummy { 
    public static ItemCollection ToItemCollection(this IEnumerable<Item> Items)
    {
        var ic = new ItemCollection();
        ic.AddRange(Items);
        return ic;
    }
}
```

So you get your result by:

```
ItemCollection ic = ItemManager.GetItems().Where(i => i.MyProperty).ToItemCollection();
```

Comment: Why would you do this? This is creating a new object and running `AddRange` on it which is significantly less efficient than just using a constructor to create an new instance of a list that is already initialized. Sorry, but this is not a *great* solution.

Comment: Dummy class is just a name for a temp class u can call it anything like Helper or what ever.

Comment: Cannot get it to work. It says that IEnumerable<Item> does not contain a definition for `ToItemCollection`.

Comment: Just to elaborate on this a bit, `AddRange` is an *O(n + m)* operation, plus however long it takes for the constructor to run. Why would you add *O(n + m)* time onto the solution, when you could do the exact same thing without creating a new class, method, and without adding the extra *O(n + m)* time? It's inefficient for the developer, as it takes longer to code, and inefficient for the code as it takes longer to run.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel.. Nothing wrong by creating new instance, im imitating SQL Linq DataContext, like objContext.Table1s.Where(...).ToList(); which a Microsoft code that should be the best practice.. plus creating instance is just a memory pointer that shouldn't affect app performance.

Comment: I have no problem with `Where`, no problem with `ToList`, and no problem with creating a new instance. I have a problem with calling `AddRange` without any rhyme or reason. And the term "best practice" is completely meaningless here, as this is in no way, shape or form a "best practice" and is not defined as such anywhere. I also don't know why you mentioned `ToList` as you are not calling it anywhere in your extension or your call to the extension.

Comment: Im ok with you if @user2609980 has access to ItemCollection code so adding ItemCollection(IEnumerable<Item> items) : base(items) constructor.

Comment: The code works and the one of @ZacharyKniebel does not in my situation. I'll accept this answer. It might be something in my code, or because of [covariance and contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx). Anyway I learned a lot from both! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers/comments have mentioned

```
(ItemCollection)ItemManager.GetItems().Where(i => i.MyProperty).ToList()
```

which will not work because of up-casting. Instead, the above will produce a `List<Item>`.

The following is what you will need to make these work. Note that you will need to have the ability to modify the `ItemCollection` class in order for this to work.

**Constructor**

If you would like to make a constructor for the `ItemCollection` class, then the following should work:

```
public ItemCollection(IEnumerable<Item> items) : base(items) {}
```

To call the constructor, you would then do the following:

```
var ic = new ItemCollection(ItemManager.GetItems().Where(i => i.MyProperty));
```

or

```
ItemCollection ic = new ItemCollection(ItemManager.GetItems().Where(i => i.MyProperty));
```

**Note about the error message**

In the comments, when asked to change `ItemCollection ic = ItemManager.GetItems.....` to `var ic = ItemManager.GetItems.....` and then tell us what the type of `ic` is, you mentioned that you got `Systems.Collections.Generic.List<T>` which would translate to `List<Item>`. The error message that you received was actually not the error message that you should have received, which is likely just due to the IDE being confused, which occasionally happens when there are errors on the page. What you should have received is something more along the lines of:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable<Item> to ItemCollection.
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not have a constructor that creates `ItemCollection` from `List<Item>` yet and do not know how to make it.

Comment: Do you have access to the `ItemCollection` class and are you able to modify it?

Comment: Yes I can. I have never done an implicit operator, but will see if it works! Interesting. 

The compiler says the `ItemCollection` needs a constructor that accepts one argument.

Comment: OR, are you able to modify the methods you have that explicitly make use of ItemCollection? (In some cases, it's possible they could be refactored to take `IEnumerable<Item>` as an argument)

Comment: @Katana314 Yes, but there are *a lot* of methods that use the `ItemCollection` so I prefer to use that one. It also feels more clean to use it.

Comment: Sorry about that - I accidentally wrote `ItemManager` instead of `ItemCollection`. I fixed it :)

Comment: Well the error is now: `user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed.`

Comment: Try without the implicit operator, and just call the constructor. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Which constructor can I call from the `ItemCollection(Ienumerable<Item> items : base(items)` constructor and how?

Comment: I have updated my post with the call to the constructor

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52687/discussion-between-user2609980-and-zachary-kniebel)